# extracting beginning of arguments from a line without using strtok()

Tags: c, string

I'm looking for the simplest way to store the beginning of each argument from a line in an array.
for example, if I pass in "gcc -o test text.c"

I want myFunction(char* line) to return a char** array where array[0] stores a pointer to the "g" in gcc, array[1] stores a pointer to the "-" in -o ... and array[3] stores a pointer to the "t" in text.c

The following code makes sense to me logically but hasn't been working ("pointers" only contains null values").

```
   for(int i = 0; i < (strlen(line)); i++){

      //if first thing is a character
      if(line[i] != ' ' && lastWasSpace == 2){
         lastWasSpace = 0;
         pointers[j] = &line[i];  //store pointer in pointers
         printf("pointers[%d] now equals %c\n", j, line[i]);
         j++;
      }

      //if first thing is a space
      else if(line[i] == ' ' && lastWasSpace == 2){
         i++;
         lastWasSpace = 1;
      }

      //while in space
      else if(line[i] == ' ' && lastWasSpace == 1){
         i++;
      } 

      //while in a word
      else if(line[i] != ' ' && lastWasSpace == 0){
         i++;
      }

      //come across a new word
      else if(line[i] != ' ' && lastWasSpace == 1){
         lastWasSpace = 0;
         pointers[j] = &line[i];  //store pointer in pointers
         printf("pointers[%d] now equals %c\n", j, line[i]);
         j++;
      }

   }
```

Comment: You should include the *entire* function, as well as the calling code and functional arguments (preferably from `main()`). And before that, *step through your code in a **debugger***. Nothing will tell you more about why your code fails to live up to expectations like walking through it in-action.

Comment: Maybe use [`getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) instead of `strtok`?